# How many different arrangements of two types of people in different rooms? Combinations question.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I having trouble wrapping my mind around this combinations/counting with restrictions example problem and would love some insight.

**Problem:** Let's say there are 5 rooms that can hold 100 people each. All rooms are at capacity. There are two types of people, those wearing blue shirts ($b$), and those wearing pink shirts ($p$).

There are 340 people wearing blue shirts and the rest are wearing pink.

How many arrangements can people be sorted such that three rooms must have all blue shirts with the remaining blue shirts being chosen from the two remaining rooms, for example, 20 blue shirts and 80 pink shirts for the remaining two rooms.

**My answer / thought process:**

For the three rooms with all blue shirts:

Room 1: $\binom{340}{100}$

Room 2: $\binom{340-100}{100}$ (100 less blue to choose from )

Room 3: $\binom{240-100}{100}$ (same logic)

In addition, I understand that since any three rooms can have all blue shirts, there are $\binom{5}{3}$ rooms that can have all blue shirts.

Now, I am just confused at the last arrangment of the remaining 40 blue shirts in the 2 remaining rooms and how to get the total number of possible arrangements.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: For the other two rooms, shirt colour doesn't matter, you are just dividing 200 people into 2 groups of 100

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all people who are wearing a blue shirt are **indistinguishable** and that the $5$ rooms are **distinguishable**.

The enumeration is

$$\binom{5}{3} \times 41. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the first factor refers to the number of ways of selecting which $(3)$ of the $(5)$ rooms will be filled with blue shirts.

Once this *decision* is made, in (for example) the $4$th room, the number of blue shirts will be some element in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,40\}$.